# Problem using Quad buffer gate (SN74HC125N)

Tags: arduino, testing

I've ordered a couple of quad buffers ([SN74HC125N](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74hc125.pdf)) from AliExpress and they don't seem to behave.

I tested it using an Arduino Uno with the following wiring:

`(Arduino pin -> SN74 pin)
1. 5v -> 14 (Vcc)
2. GND (Under 5v) -> 7 (GND)
3. GND -> 1 (OE not)
4. 5v -> 2 (1A)`

The output (1Y) was connected to a led + resistor, sharing the Uno ground.

Here's a schematic (I couldn't find the same chip but it has the same pin numbers) :
[image]

This configuration completely shut the Uno down (On Light is off, USB disconnects). It shuts down the immediately after I connect pin 1 to gnd.

I tested 2 parts this way, both gave similar results. Am I doing something wrong?
Could these parts be faulty?

Comment: can you show us a schematic drawing please.

Comment: I suggest you put a series 1K resistor at minimum between 5V Uno pin and the input pin of the buffer too, it's possible the buffer is low input impedance.. and it's sinking huge currents into it's input pin. I find this very unlikely though, and you have a short circuit somewhere else

Comment: 'To ensure the high-impedance state during power up or power down, OE should be tied to VCC through a pullup resistor; the minimum value of the resistor is determined by the current-sinking capability of the driver.'   


maybe that has to do something with it. Your question is still a bit strange, try to clarify it with a schematic or a photo of your wiring.

Comment: I think you may short your power supply to ground, when you connect pin 1, please check your circuit. A buffer should have high impedance inputs. So normally, it won't absorb so much current to shut your system down!

Comment: @TJ that is for making it go high impedance mode, which the OP is not interested in right now. It's the act of enabling the chip with OE1 going to GND that kills it somehow.

Comment: Added a schematic drawing (never used fritzing - It's surprisingly simple and fun). Pin 1 is connected with a green wire

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem here is that you don't know how to use a breadboard.

Your chip **must** straddle the gutter in the middle, otherwise all the pins opposite each other will be shorted out.

Also it looks like the chip is backwards - though that may be Fritzing's fault.

Comment: I can't believe it, but you're right. Used breadboards for years and didn't seem to notice I've shorted the chip pns. I guess I'm lucky nothing burnt!!! <feeling ashamed> Thanks.

Comment: Also, flipped the chip.